# can c++ using cin to read one digit like scanf

Tags: c++

does c++ have similar measure like `scanf("%1d)` read only one digit in `cin >>`

or only `#include <cstdin>` and use `scanf`

I try to use setw() but it seem to use in string

Comment: `"I try to use setw() but it seem to use in string"` -- Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Answer (score 3):

Here, take a look at this method

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout << "Enter a number : ";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    int num = input[0] - 48; // converting char to int by ASCII values
    // int num = input[0] - '0';  can also be used
    cout << num;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Even if many digits are entered as input, the program only accepts the first digit.

Comment: sorry is one not long

Answer (score 0):

A digit is nothing else than a single character.

In order to read a single character from [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), you can use [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), or you can use [`std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Using `operator>>`:

```
char digit;
std::cin >> digit;
```

Using `std::istream::get`:

```
char digit;
std::cin.get( &digit );
```

In order to convert `char digit` to an integer, assuming that `digit` is in the range `'0'` to `'9'`, you can write the following:

```
int number = digit - '0';
```

You can do this because the ISO C++ standard guarantees that the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are stored consecutively in the character set. For example, in [ASCII](https://asciichart.com/), the characters `'0'` to `'9'` have the character codes `48` to `57`. Therefore, if you simply substract `48` (which is the character code for `'0'`) from the character code, you will get a result between `0` and `9`, which is the value of the digit.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char digit;

    //prompt user for input
    std::cout << "Please enter a digit: ";

    //attempt to read a single character
    std::cin >> digit;

    //verify that no input error occurred
    if ( !std::cin )
    {
        printf( "Input error!\n" );
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that character is in the range '0' to '9'
    if ( ! ( '0' <= digit && digit <= '9' ) )
    {
        printf( "Character is not a digit!\n" );
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //convert digit to integer
    number = digit - '0';

    //print result
    std::cout <<
        "The digit was successfully converted to " << number << ".\n";
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter a digit: 7
The digit was successfully converted to 7.
```

It only accepts digits:

```
Please enter a digit: a
Character is not a digit!
```

It will only read the first digit, not a whole number:

```
Please enter a digit: 38
The digit was successfully converted to 3.
```

Comment: can I use int type to load this digit

Comment: @包在我身上: I have edited my answer in order to also answer your comment.